# How to insert a new node(as prelast) on the list (Linked List)

Tags: java, data-structures

Hello I have done the interface (and each one method)

```
  public   interface List
    {
        public boolean isEmpty();
    
        public int size();
    
        public void insertFirst(Object data);
    
        public void insertLast(Object data);
    
        public Object removeFirst() throws ListEmptyException;
    
        public Object removeLast() throws ListEmptyException;
    }
```

I have a class with name  List and the constructor of it and with all  those methods.
I want to create one method with name insertprelast (using all methods I have done from the interface)  so that it will insert a new node as prelast on the list.In case it can not be insert will throw an exception.

What I did was this :
**1.** I create a new class **ListTooSmallException**

```
public class ListTooSmallException extends Exception {
        public ListTooSmallException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
```

**2.** I add on the class List the method but I don't know how can I do so that I will have the prelast

```
public void insertprelast(Object obj) throws ListTooSmallException {
    
      

    if (obj == null) {
        throw new ListTooSmallException(" wrong");
    } else {
       // i dont know how to do it  
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: That exception makes no sense; if obj is supposed to be the item being inserted what does that have to do with the list being too small?

Comment: you right , my mind was on the other part than exception and I didn't think about the part of the exception .I don't know the part that how can I do the obj show the prelast.

Comment: Dave Newton if it was the last a similar example would be like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331507/add-node-to-end-of-linked-list ,i want the prelast

Comment: Think about it logically: if you know the last item in the list you know where the item needs to be inserted, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that you remove the last item from the list, and keep a reference to it, and then insert the given argument at the end, to finally add the saved node back to the end.

Something like this:

```
public void insertPreLast(Object obj) throws ListTooSmallException {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw ListTooSmallException("List cannot be empty when calling insertPreLast");
    }
    Object saved = removeLast();
    insertLast(obj);
    insertLast(saved);
}
```